# Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted when resizing image

Tags: php, image, rotation

I'm trying to upload an image (no problem), rotate the image if necessary (no problem) and then resize it (that's when the problem happens).
Once the image has been rotated, I get the following error when using the `imagecreatefromjpeg` function:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9288 bytes).
```

Here's my code

```
<?php
$path='uploads/test7.jpg';

$exif = exif_read_data($path);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) 
{
    $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
        break;
        case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
        break;
        case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
        break;
        default:
        $image = $imageResource;
    }
}

imagejpeg($image, $path,100);

$newImage= imagecreatefromjpeg($path); //this line generates an error
?>
```

Comment: Memory limit seems to be set to 128M, either increase it, or limit file upload size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have mentioned the error you get:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9288 bytes).

This means your *memory limit* is to too low. Try to increase it yourself with `ini_set('memory_limit, '256M')`, ask your admin to increase the limit or upgrade your hosting-package.

You can read more about in the [PHP manual - Resource limits](https://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help guys and sorry for the late reply.
I finally solved my problem by using imagedestroy before creating a new image.